# Java String array parsing and getting data

Tags: java

String input data is

```
{phone=333-333-3333, pr_specialist_email=null, sic_code=2391, status=ACTIVE, address1=E.BALL Drive, fax=333-888-3315, naics_code=325220, client_id=862222, bus_name=ENTERPRISES, address2=null, contact=BYRON BUEGE}
```

Key and values will increase in the array. 
I want to get the value for each key ie myString.get("phone") should return 333-333-3333
I am using Java 1.7, is there any tools I can use this to parse the data and get the values.

Some of my input is having values like,

```
{phone=000000002,Desc="Light PROPERTITES, LCC", Address1="C/O ABC RICHARD",Address2="6508 THOUSAND OAKS BLVD.,",Adress3="SUITE 1120",city=MEMPHIS,state=TN,name=,dob=,DNE=,}
```

Comma separator doesn't work here

Comment: Parse it and put it into a map instead of an array.

Comment: Why not write a simple parser yourself?

Comment: *"is there any tools I can use this to parse the data and get the values"* Yes, there are JSON parser ... you can use google to find tutorials.

Comment: @Tom this doesn't look like a json string..Anyhow he can refer that to create his own parser

Comment: @Tom, Json requires data in "key":"value", but my String is not in that format. I need to take whole String as a json parser, but that is not going to work for my requirement.

Comment: If you're not using a known format, how a parser might already exists ? Sometimes solution is not given by tools but simply by thinking ;)

Comment: @Madhan Yes, you're right. Thnx.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple function that will do exacly what you want. It takes your string as an input and returns a Hashmap containing all the keys and values.

```
private HashMap<String, String> getKeyValueMap(String str) {

    // Trim the curly ({}) brackets
    str = str.trim().substring(1, str.length() - 1);

    // Split all the key-values tuples
    String[] split = str.split(",");

    String[] keyValue;
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String tuple : split) {

        // Seperate the key from the value and put them in the HashMap
        keyValue = tuple.split("=");
        map.put(keyValue[0].trim(), keyValue[1].trim());

    }

    // Return the HashMap with all the key-value combinations
    return map;

}
```

*Note: This will not work if there's ever a '=' or ',' character in any of the key names or values.*

To get any value, all you have to do is:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = getKeyValueMap(...);
String value = map.get(key);
```

Comment: You beated me by just a couple minutes ;)

Comment: @Iamsomeone I like how we wrote the exact same code. Your vision on the problem was quite on point and your code is fantastic :D

Comment: If this format is a replacement of something like json.Parser for it needs to consider nested levels

Comment: @bl3e From the informations given by OP, there is no nested levels. If he adds that constraint then I will oblige.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple parser yourself. I'll exclude error checking in this code for brevity.

You should first remove the { and } characters, then split by ', ' and split each resulting string by =. At last add the results into a map.

```
String input = ...;
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
input = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1);
String elements[] = input.split(", ");
for(String elem : elements)
{
    String values[] = elem.split("=");
    map.put(values[0].trim(), values[1].trim());
}
```

Then, to retrieve a value, just do

```
String value = map.get("YOURKEY");
```

Comment: To make your code a bit better, you can do something like this `input = input.substring(input.indexOf('{') + 1, input.lastIndexOf('}'));`. That way your code won't break with a String like this `"      { data }     "`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Google Core Libraries for Java API" [MapSplitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html) to do your job.

First remove the curly braces using substring method and use the below code to do your job.

```
Map<String, String> splitKeyValues = Splitter.on(",")
    .omitEmptyStrings()
    .trimResults()
    .withKeyValueSeparator("=")
    .split(stringToSplit);
```